# Bring partially ordered list items into a total order

Tags: c++, stl

Think of some type `S` that implements `<=` and `==` (and what you can build from that). The order given by `S::operator<=` is no total order, i.e., it may happen that you find `x, y` of type `S` such that neither `x <= y` nor `y <= x`.

Given a `vector<S> v`, I want to bring elements of `v` in some order such that `v[i] < v[j]` implies `i < j`.

To achieve this, I could choose a fixed total order on `S` that refines `<=`. But that takes no advantage of the possibility that the elements of `v` are probably already (almost) in in the correct order w.r.t. some other total order on `S`.

So, how would bring `v` in an order satisfying my requirements with least effort; at best, using stl algorithms?

Comment: Normally you'd use `<` for a strict weak order, not `<=`

Comment: You describe [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The C++ standard library doesn't provide that; you'd have to implement your own or find a third-party library.

Comment: @Caleth I come from math, where ≤ is a common symbol for a partial order; that's why.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks; that's what I was looking for. Feel free to post that as an answer (or mark my question as duplicate, as it seems to be).